# How do questions answered in comments get closed?

Tags: discussion

I just steered the person who asked [What does the ampersand do in a print statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274723/what-does-the-ampersand-do-in-a-print-statement) to an example that appears to satisfy him.

How does a question like this get closed (and preferably hidden, as I don't think they add much value to the site)?

Comment: You could flag that question as a duplicate

Comment: his question wasn't a duplicate (I didn't check) - but an answer to another question contained enough information to answer his question.  I'm not taking credit for the answer - but to see the answer a new user would have to find the comment and follow the link... not ideal...

Comment: Sometimes I'd really like to flag comments as "Not a comment; it's an answer"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know the answer is "bitwise and" then finding duplicates will likely be easier working backwards. Just Google "java bitwise and site:stackoverflow.com" and select an appropriate duplicate.

If you can't find one then it is up to you whether or not you want to rewrite the comment as a fuller answer.

Personally I've voted to close as duplicate of [How Does The Bitwise & (AND) Work In Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17256644/73226). The stuff about the print statement isn't really relevant they just want to understand why `10 & 7 == 2`

Comment: I'll have to relax my criteria for duplicates to include "close enough to provide an answer"